# <nav> HTML tag shows different in Mozilla than in other browser

Tags: html, css, nav, mozilla

I'm not a front-end developer in fact I've basically copy-pasted an open-source nav bar and pasted it on my project editing the colors and id tags.

For some reason on Chrome, Edge, Opera the nav bar works perfectly while in Mozilla looks very buggy (see screenshot as I don't know how to describe it - left looks ok, right looks buggy) and I do not know why. Below is my code (don't mind the Django code injected) :

[image]

### HTML

```
<nav id="main_nav" class="sidebar close"> <!-- cloe class to keep it close -->
        <header>
            <div class="image-text">
                <span class="image">
                    <img src="logo.png" alt="">
                </span>

                <div class="text logo-text">
                    <span class="name">The Groove Cartel</span>
                    <span class="profession">Playlist Manager</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <i class='bx bx-chevron-right toggle'></i>
        </header>

        <div class="menu-bar">
            <div class="menu">

                

                <ul class="menu-links">
                    <li class="nav-link">
                        <a href="/">
                            <i class='bx bx-home-alt icon' ></i>
                            <span class="text nav-text">Home</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    
                    
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="bottom-content">



                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class="">
                    <a href="{% url 'account' user.username%}">
                        <i class='bx bxs-user-detail icon' ></i>
                        <span class="text nav-text">My profile</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                
                {% endif %}

                <li class="mode">
                    <div class="sun-moon">
                        <i class='bx bx-moon icon moon'></i>
                        <i class='bx bx-sun icon sun'></i>
                    </div>
                    <span class="mode-text text">Dark mode</span>

                    <div class="toggle-switch">
                        <span class="switch"></span>
                    </div>
                </li>

            </div>
        </div>

    </nav>
```

### CSS

```
/* ===== Sidebar ===== */
 .sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 280px;
    padding: 10px 14px;
    background: var(--sidebar-color);
    transition: var(--tran-05);
    z-index: 100;
}
.sidebar.close{
    width: 88px;
}

/* ===== Reusable code - Here ===== */
.menu-links{
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}

.sidebar li{
    height: 50px;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0px !important;
}

.sidebar header .image,
.sidebar .icon{
    min-width: 60px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.sidebar .icon{
    min-width: 60px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.sidebar .text,
.sidebar .icon{
    color: var(--text-color);
    transition: var(--tran-03);
}

.sidebar .text{
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Poppins-Medium;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar.close .text{
    opacity: 0;
}
/* =========================== */

.sidebar header{
    position: relative;
}

.sidebar header .image-text{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.sidebar header .logo-text{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
header .image-text .name {
    margin-top: 2px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Poppins-SemiBold;
}

header .image-text .profession{
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    display: block;
}

.sidebar header .image{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.sidebar header .image img{
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.sidebar header .toggle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -25px;
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    color: var(--sidebar-color);
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}

body.dark .sidebar header .toggle{
    color: var(--text-color);
}

.sidebar.close .toggle{
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
}

.sidebar .menu{
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.sidebar li.search-box{
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: var(--primary-color-light);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}

.sidebar li.search-box input{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background-color: var(--primary-color-light);
    color: var(--text-color);
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Poppins-Medium;
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}
.sidebar li a{
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: var(--tran-03);
}

.sidebar li a:hover{
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
.sidebar li a:hover .icon,
.sidebar li a:hover .text{
    color: var(--sidebar-color);
}
body.dark .sidebar li a:hover .icon,
body.dark .sidebar li a:hover .text{
    color: var(--text-color);
}

.sidebar .menu-bar{
    height: calc(100% - 55px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.menu-bar::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
}
.sidebar .menu-bar .mode{
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: var(--primary-color-light);
    position: relative;
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}

.menu-bar .mode .sun-moon{
    height: 50px;
    width: 60px;
}

.mode .sun-moon i{
    position: absolute;
}
.mode .sun-moon i.sun{
    opacity: 0;
}
body.dark .mode .sun-moon i.sun{
    opacity: 1;
}
body.dark .mode .sun-moon i.moon{
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu-bar .bottom-content .toggle-switch{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle-switch .switch{
    position: relative;
    height: 22px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: var(--toggle-color);
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}

.switch::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-color: var(--sidebar-color);
    transition: var(--tran-04);
}

body.dark .switch::before{
    left: 20px;
}

.home{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 280px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: calc(100% - 280px);
    background-color: var(--body-color);
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}
.home .text{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Poppins-Medium;
    color: var(--text-color);
    padding: 12px 60px;
}

.sidebar.close ~ .home{
    left: 78px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: calc(100% - 78px);
}
body.dark .home .text{
    color: var(--text-color);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar <-- read here and here -> https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1432935

Comment: @SimoneRossaini thanks, didn't know about that. Using `scrollbar-width: none;` don't work tho

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with your code can you create one with tool `[<>]` or fiddle?